# Problems counting rows and columns with no spaces in a matrix

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the number of rows and columns in a matrix file. The matrix doesn't have spaces between the characters but does have separate lines. The sample down below should return 3 rows and 5 columns but that's not happening.

Also when I print the matrix each line has \n in it. I want to remove that. I tried `.split('\n')` but that didn't help. I ran this script earlier with a different data set separated with commas I had the `line.split(',')` in the code and that worked it would return the correct number of rows and columns as well as print the matrix with no `\n`, I'm not sure what changed by removing the comma from the `line.split()`.

```
import sys
import numpy


with open(sys.argv[1], "r") as f:

    m = [[char for char in line.split(' ')] for line in f if line.strip('\n') ]    
 
m_size = numpy.shape(m)
print(m)
print("%s, %s" % m_size)
```

Sample data:

```
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
```

Output:

```
[['aaaaa\n'], ['bbbbb\n'], ['ccccc']]
3, 1,
```

Comment: You can count the no.of characters in a line to get the columns.

Comment: Please use a spell-checker when posting here robothead - it is not a chatroom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    m = np.array([[char for char in line.strip()] for line in f])
```

```
>>> m
array([['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
       ['b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b'],
       ['c', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']], dtype='<U1')

>>> m.shape
(3, 5)
```